# Stand-alone ASP.NET pages

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration, web-config

ASP.NET configuration [allows to specify base type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for pages in an application:

> pageBaseType Optional String attribute. Specifies the base to use when
>   the pages are stand-alone only. This is overridden by the inherits
>   attribute in a stand-alone file. The default is "System.Web.UI.Page".

What does *stand-alone only* mean? Can you give an example when a page isn't stand-alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A page is standalone when it has no page directive telling it which class to inherit from. This directive would be used in that case.

Comment: Do you mean an .ASPX page that has no `Inherits` attribute in its `Page` directive? Can you refer to MSDN to clarify that?

Comment: Other than the link you posted above, which pretty much says the same thing & having proved it with code? No I don't have a link. But I'm sure if you & me Google enough we'll find one.